# Gulp + gulp-compass compile, unchanged files being reinjected to BrowserSync

Tags: gulp, compass, gulp-watch, browser-sync

I've got a Gulp task setup to compile .scss files with compass, and also another task running which injects changed CSS into the browser via BrowserSync.

```
gulp.task('browser-sync', function () {
    var options = {
        files: './public/css/**/*.css',
        proxy: ecs_domain,
        port: 3000
    };

    browserSync(options);
});

gulp.task('compass', function () {
    gulp.src('./scss/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(compass({
            css: cssOutput,
            sass: 'scss'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(cssOutput))
        .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});
```

The problem I'm finding is that when compass is run, I get output like in the following snippet:

```
identical public/css/main.css
[BS] File changed: public/css/main.css
```

Even though the file *main.css* hasn't changed, compass somehow touches it, making BrowserSync think it has changed, meaning that even if only one file changes, the entire set of CSS files are re-injected to the browser.

Is there a way to leave the identical/unchanged *.css files un-*touch*-ed so BrowserSync can only load the files that **actually** changed?

We have quite a few files and makes the whole process quite slow.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a partial solution. I installed gulp-changed and redirected output from compass to a temporary .out folder. Then created a watch to run gulp-changed when files differ from public/css and .out version using the following task:

```
gulp.task('copy-changed-css', function () {
    gulp.src('.out/**/*.css')
        .pipe(changed('public/css', {hasChanged: changed.compareSha1Digest}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/css'))
});
```

Comment: hmm, I have the same issue. can you share the compass and browser-sync tasks too?